# How do I identify the source of a UDP packet in an access point?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, qos

I'm creating a kind of access point.

I capture all packets, of all the types, from my machine, in order to prioritize them before forwarding them, according to the default Quality of Service (QoS) classes.

By calling `socket` with the `ETH_P_ALL` parameter , I can get all incoming packets of any protocol type:

```
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == ERROR)  {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
```

By using `ethhdr`, `iphdr`, `tcphdr` and `udphdr` structs I can't retrieve information on which application sent each packet.

However, both Voip and SNMP use UDP, and I don't know which of the two sent me UDP package.

I'd like to know which applications are sending the UDP packets, so I may follow the QoS classes and forward some packets (e.g. conversational voice) before others (e.g. e-mail).

In order to recognize the protocol, should I use the list of TCP and UDP port numbers?

Comment: "*should I use the list of TCP and UDP port numbers*": Without (trying to) inspect the packets' payload you probably have no other possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell *for sure* which application sent a packet - Only the sender itself knows this. If I understand correctly, what you want is to detect which protocol is being used. Then you have 2 possibilities:

1. Assume an application based on the destination port set on the TCP/UDP packet - the [list of TCP/UDP port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) or your `/etc/services` (if you're on Linux/Unix/OSX/etc) might be of help;
2. Analyse the packet contents and match it against known protocol signatures (like an IDS does - see [Snort rules](http://manual.snort.org/node28.html) for example). Note you may need some form of conntrack to make this work reliably;

Comment: Option two is an expensive one. Also doing so might raise ethic objections.

Comment: @alk: quite expensive indeed. As for the other point, while I agree, I must ask: How does a NGFW do this without raising ethic objections? The only answer I know (currently) is: User terms and conditions + privacy policy.

Comment: Could you suggest me some interesting papers or docs about how IDS recognize protocol signatures?
Sincerly, I don't know where to start.

Comment: @elmazzun I don't recall any good papers/docs right now, but I'd suggest looking into [Snort's manual](http://manual.snort.org/) or maybe [other Snort documents](https://www.snort.org/documents)

Comment: Thank you, I'll start from there.